# Angular does not seem to react on callback

Tags: angular, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a small webapp with a wishlist. Adding items works. However, when invoking the delete operation, Angular does not seem to wait for the response (neither the succes, nor failure callback is invoked). Instead, angular navigates away to the root of the application.

I have defined following angular service:

```
import {Item} from '../shared/Item.model';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

 baseUrl: String = 'http://localhost:8080/';

 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

addWishListItem(userId: string, itemToAdd: Item) {
   return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + '/rest/person/private/' + userId + '/wishlist', itemToAdd);
  }

 removeWishListItem(userId: string, itemToRemove: Item) {
    return this.httpClient.delete(this.baseUrl + '/rest/person/private/' + userId + '/wishlist/' + itemToRemove.id);
  }
}
```

The component invoking the service is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Item} from '../shared/Item.model';
import {UserService} from './user.service';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {User} from '../shared/User.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wishlist',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User;

  constructor(private userService: UserService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUser(this.route.snapshot.params['id'], false).subscribe(
      (user: User) => {
        this.user = user;
        if (this.user === undefined) {
          this.router.navigate(['notfound']);
      }
    }
   );
  }

  onItemAdded(itemData: Item) {
    this.userService.addWishListItem(this.user.privateId, itemData).subscribe(
      (user: User) => {
        this.user = user;
      }
    );
  }

  onItemRemoved(itemData: Item) {
    const oldId = this.user.privateId;
    this.userService.removeWishListItem(this.user.privateId, itemData).subscribe(
      (response) => {console.log('Hehe'); },
      (error) => {console.log('oops'); }
    );
  }
}
```

None of the two callbacks are executed. The actual delete operation is invoked on the backend (I can break there). For completion, here is the (spring boot / kotlin) service invoked by the angular component:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/person")
class PersonEndpoint(

        private val personRepository: PersonRepository,
        private val personWithPrivateIdToFactory: PersonWithPrivateIdToFactory,
        private val wislistItemDomainFactory: WishListItemDomainFactory
) {


    /**
     * Adds a wishlistitem to a user if that user exists and returns the updated user.
     */
    @CrossOrigin(origins = ["http://localhost:4200"])
    @PostMapping("/private/{id}/wishlist")
    @Transactional
    fun addWishlistItem(@PathVariable("id") privateId: UUID,
                        @RequestBody item: WishlistItemTo): PersonWithPrivateIdTo {
        val person = personRepository.findByPrivateId(privateId);
        if (person != null) {
            person.addItem(wislistItemDomainFactory.toDomain(item))
            return personWithPrivateIdToFactory.toTo(personRepository.save(person))
        } else {
            throw NotFoundException("No such user found.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds a wishlistitem to a user if that user exists and returns the updated user.
     */
    @CrossOrigin(origins = ["http://localhost:4200"])
    @DeleteMapping("/private/{id}/wishlist/{itemId}")
    @Transactional
    fun removeWishlistItem(@PathVariable("id") privateId: UUID,
                           @PathVariable("itemId") itemToRemove: Long) {
        val person = personRepository.findByPrivateId(privateId);
        if (person != null) {
            person.removeItemById(itemToRemove)
            personRepository.save(person)
        } else {
            throw NotFoundException("No such user found.");
        }
    }
}
```

The addition works perfectly: the updated user is returned and displayed on screen. I initially wanted the delete to work in a similar fashion (returning the updated user), but I have currently removed that as I thought the body of a delete operation was probably ignored by Spring Boot or angular. However, I would need to react to the completion of the delete operation to reload the user.

Edit:

As the html was requested, here is the html of the usercomponent:

```
<div class="wishlisttitle">Wishlist of {{user?.name}}</div>

<app-wishlist-edit
  (itemAdded)="onItemAdded($event)"
  class="submargin"></app-wishlist-edit>

<div *ngIf="user !== undefined">

<div *ngIf="user.wishlist.items.length == 0 &&" class="topmargin">Empty. Please add elements.</div>

  <app-wishlist-item
    *ngFor="let item of user.wishlist.items"
    [wishListItem]="item"
    (itemRemoved)="onItemRemoved($event)"
  ></app-wishlist-item>

</div>
```

Here is the html of the wishlist item component:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="card bg-light border-dark">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{item.name}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text"><a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.url}}</a></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onRemoveClicked()">Remove Item</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And for the edit:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <label for="name"><i>Item (Short description)</i></label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="itemName" type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <label for="url"><i>Link</i></label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="itemLink" type="number" class="form-control" id="url">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 align-self-end">
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onSubmit()">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Edit:

The issue is solved: it was the  which obviously triggered the navigation. After changing this, the problem was quickly resolved.

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where does it naviagate to?

Comment: It can be an HTML issue, can you add it to your question please ?

Comment: After adding the html and looking for an additional hour, I finally saw the href="#" in the link. Dumb of me. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your delete method in your rest service is not returning a response. Maybe you could add `return person` on successful delete.

You may also want to change your http call function to something like this.

```
    removeWishListItem(userId: string, itemToRemove: Item) {
       return this.httpClient
          .delete(this.baseUrl + '/rest/person/private/' + userId + '/wishlist/' + itemToRemove.id)
          .map(response => response.json())
          .pipe(
             catchError(this.handleError)
          );
```

Comment: HttpClient automatically parse to JSON.